# map (align) smaller to larger sequence in r

Tags: r, sorting, dataset, alignment

I have following framework dataset:

```
master <- data.frame (namest = c("A","B", "C","D", "E", "F"), 
 position =c( 0, 10, 20, 25, 30, 35))
master
      namest position
    1      A        0
    2      B       10
    3      C       20
    4      D       25
    5      E       30
    6      F       35
```

This is bigger map (say road map) where there is name of place and position. Now in second survey we have smaller subsets (many, here just 3).

```
subset1 <- data.frame (namest = c("I", "A", "ii", "iii", "B"), 
 position = c(0, 10, 12, 14, 20))  
subset1
  namest position
1      I        0
2      A       10
3     ii       12
4    iii       14
5      B       20

subset2 <- data.frame (namest = c("E", "vii", "F"), position = c(0, 3,5))
 subset2
  namest position
1      E        0
2    vii        3
3      F        5

subset3 <- data.frame (namest = c("D", "vi", "v", "C", "iv"), 
   position = c(0, 2, 3, 5, 8))
subset3
  namest position
1      D        0
2     vi        2
3      v        3
4      C        5
5     iv        8
```

You can see that each subsets have at two names that are common to master, for example D and C in subset3.

Now I want to combine these subsets to make more detailed master. Means that new namest will be positioned in new map. See that some of subset (see subset3) have reverse order compared to master.

Thus expected output is:

```
subsetalign <- data.frame(subsett = c(rep ("A-B", nrow(subset1)),
rep("C-D", nrow(subset3)), 
rep("E-F", nrow(subset2))), namest =  c(c("I", "A", "ii", "iii", "B"), 
rev (c("D", "vi", "v", "C", "iv")),c("E", "vii", "F")), 
position = c(subset1$position, rev (subset3$position), subset2$position))

 subsetalign
   subsett namest position
1      A-B      I        0
2      A-B      A       10
3      A-B     ii       12
4      A-B    iii       14
5      A-B      B       20
6      C-D     iv        8
7      C-D      C        5
8      C-D      v        3
9      C-D     vi        2
10     C-D      D        0
11     E-F      E        0
12     E-F    vii        3
13     E-F      F        5
```

The output process can be visualized as (I do not mean to create such figure,at this point, just to explain better):

[image]

Edits: 
It is not simiply rbind due to two things:

(a) The subset are ordered based on how their comman namest are arranged in master file.
For example subset1 (A-B) + subset3 (C-D) + subset2 (E-F), as the order in master is A-B-C-D-E-F

(b) Also if the subset have reverse order than master, they should be reversed. 
In subset 3, the order of namest is "D"-"vi"-"v"-"C"-"iv", but in master D comes after C, so this sustet 3 should reversed before binding.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding this, but it looks like you are simply `rbind`ing several data frames. Perhaps `do.call(rbind,...)` if there are a lot of them?

Comment: @joran is there is some differences more than simply rbind (1) as they are ordered by master (A-B (subset 1), C-D (subset3), and E-F (subset2)), (2) if the order is reverse eg. C-D in master but D-C in subset, the subset order is reveresed before binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the subsets are in a list

```
subsets <- list(subset1, subset2, subset3)
```

The location of the anchors in the master are

```
idx <- lapply(subsets, function(x, y) match(x$namest, y$namest), master)
```

The orientation of each subset is

```
orientation <- sapply(idx, function(elt) unique(diff(elt[!is.na(elt)])))
```

And the position in the master is

```
position <- sapply(idx, function(elt) min(elt, na.rm=TRUE))
```

The subsets can be ordered `subsets[order(position)]`, reversed if necessary

```
updt <- Map(function(elt, dir) {
    if (dir == -1)
        elt[rev(seq_len(nrow(elt))),] 
   else elt
}, subsets[order(position)], orientation[order(position)])
```

and `rbind`ed together, `do.call(rbind, updt)`. This is assuming that all intervals in `master` are represented exactly once.